# How to change the bounding box thickness and label text in yolov5?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolov5

I am using YOLOv5s for object detection on custom datasets, there are multiple objects in given video, sometimes label text and bounding box thickness looks very bad. how can I customize these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using `detect.py`, pass in the following arguments to adjust the labels and bounding boxes:

```
--line-thickness 1
--hide-labels True
--hide-conf True
```

For the `--line-thickness` argument, pass in an integer value to adjust the thickness, for labels and confidence, they are set to `False` by default. Setting them to `True` will hide them.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using `--hide-labels True` or `hide-conf True`. 
Under certain circumstances you can encounter an ErrorMessage. Only `--hide-labels` and `--hide-conf` should work perfectly fine.
Here is a list of arguments you can use with `detect.py`.

```
detect.py [-h] [--weights WEIGHTS [WEIGHTS ...]] [--source SOURCE]
                 [--data DATA] [--imgsz IMGSZ [IMGSZ ...]]
                 [--conf-thres CONF_THRES] [--iou-thres IOU_THRES]
                 [--max-det MAX_DET] [--device DEVICE] [--view-img]
                 [--save-txt] [--save-conf] [--save-crop] [--nosave]
                 [--classes CLASSES [CLASSES ...]] [--agnostic-nms]
                 [--augment] [--visualize] [--update] [--project PROJECT]
                 [--name NAME] [--exist-ok] [--line-thickness LINE_THICKNESS]
                 [--hide-labels] [--hide-conf] [--half] [--dnn]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In detect.py file you can see there is a function called run where you can manipulate your detection results

```
def run(
        weights=ROOT / 'yolov5s.pt',  # model path or triton URL
        source=ROOT / 'data/images',  # file/dir/URL/glob/screen/0(webcam)
        data=ROOT / 'data/coco128.yaml',  # dataset.yaml path
        imgsz=(640, 640),  # inference size (height, width)
        conf_thres=0.25,  # confidence threshold
        iou_thres=0.45,  # NMS IOU threshold
        max_det=1000,  # maximum detections per image
        device='',  # cuda device, i.e. 0 or 0,1,2,3 or cpu
        view_img=False,  # show results
        save_txt=False,  # save results to *.txt
        save_conf=False,  # save confidences in --save-txt labels
        save_crop=False,  # save cropped prediction boxes
        nosave=False,  # do not save images/videos
        classes=None,  # filter by class: --class 0, or --class 0 2 3
        agnostic_nms=False,  # class-agnostic NMS
        augment=False,  # augmented inference
        visualize=False,  # visualize features
        update=False,  # update all models
        project=ROOT / 'runs/detect',  # save results to project/name
        name='exp',  # save results to project/name
        exist_ok=False,  # existing project/name ok, do not increment
        line_thickness=3,  # bounding box thickness (pixels)
        hide_labels=False,  # hide labels
        hide_conf=False,  # hide confidences
        half=False,  # use FP16 half-precision inference
        dnn=False,  # use OpenCV DNN for ONNX inference
        vid_stride=1,  # video frame-rate stride
):
```

Now you can adjust the line thickness here

**line_thickness=3**